# VisualBasic Power Pack how to include the libraries automatically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build-process, vb-power-pack

My C# application uses the VB Power Pack to print. The computers that I am installing my application on do NOT have the VB Power Pack.

How can I include the appropiate libraries bundled with my application?

Comment: What work? It's not a coding question. Its about building and deploying and how to include a library in VS2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you added a reference to VB Power Pack.

Just right-click the reference, go to *Properties* and set *Local copy* to *True*.
The referenced assemblies will be copied in your bin folder during compilation.

Comment: Just another question. When I created my project I called it X. Now I want to build it and have the EXE called Y.exe. Currently I am manually renaming it to Y.exe. Is there a way to name the EXE when building?

Comment: In your project's Properties page, go to Application tab and change the value for Assembly name to Y.